# Best macro tool for webbrowser

Tags: macros, firefox-addon, phpmyadmin, browser

I need to automate some webbrowser operation. Basically I need to import the result  of some  SQL queries via phpMyAdmin (I can't do direct SQl because my provider doesn't allow it AND I also tried using CURL or WGet but I couldn't get it work). Anyway, as it always the same files I though I could use macro. I thought using Vimperator/pentadactyl but it doesn't work as I need the macro to record file selection etc ....

So what would be the best (more popular) plugin to do the job. I was thinking of Selenium but I've seen other plugin which could do it.

Alternatively a full CLI version allowing to execute SQL remotely would be amazing too.

Comment: Mozmill might do what you're after: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Mozmill

Comment: looks interesting indeed. I'll have a look at it. Why not posting it as an answer ?

Comment: I read somewhere that stackoverflow frowns on people just posting a link as an answer, so I figured I'd post it as a comment.

Comment: My question is about a fire-fox add-ons, so a link toward is a valid answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can automation test for web to do the work replaced for macro.
With my knowledge macro using vbscript. some programs support for macro are Access, Excel, mapics(as400).

Comment: I'm not speaking of macro excel but of macro is in general meaning (look at the 'macros' tag definition